# Additional parameter on spring-authorization-server

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, spring-oauth2

What I'm going to do is like this.

1. post additional parameter when user submit on consent page.
2. send posted additional parameter to redirect uri.

I've checked through `AuthorizationRequestConverter` that `OAuth2AuthorizationCodeRequestAuthenticationToken` has the parameter which user has uploaded.

But I don't know why `OAuth2Authorization` doesn't save additional parameters on Database.
Cause of above I cant' reach to additional parameters and can't post data to redirect URI.

---

I've referred to this repository.

[sjohnr/spring-authorization-server](https://github.com/sjohnr/spring-authorization-server/tree/springone-2021)

---

Here's my auth server configuration

1. AuthorizationServerConfig

```java
    @Bean
    @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
    public SecurityFilterChain authServerSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer<HttpSecurity> authorizationServerConfigurer =
                new OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer<>();

        RequestMatcher endpointsMatcher = authorizationServerConfigurer.getEndpointsMatcher();

        authorizationServerConfigurer
                .authorizationEndpoint(authorizationEndPoint ->
                    authorizationEndPoint
                        .consentPage(CUSTOM_CONSENT_PAGE_URI)
                        .authorizationRequestConverter(customAuthorizationRequestConverter())
                        .authorizationResponseHandler(authorizationResponseHandler())
                )
                .withObjectPostProcessor(new ObjectPostProcessor<OAuth2AuthorizationCodeRequestAuthenticationProvider>() {
                    @Override
                    public <O extends OAuth2AuthorizationCodeRequestAuthenticationProvider> O postProcess(O object) {
                        object.setAuthenticationValidatorResolver(createDefaultAuthenticationValidatorResolver());
                        return object;
                    }
                });

        http
            .requestMatcher(endpointsMatcher)
            .authorizeRequests(authorizeRequest ->
                authorizeRequest.anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            .formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults())
            .csrf(csrf -> csrf.ignoringRequestMatchers(endpointsMatcher))
            .apply(authorizationServerConfigurer);

        return http.build();
    }

    private AuthenticationConverter customAuthorizationRequestConverter() {
        final OAuth2AuthorizationCodeRequestAuthenticationConverter delegate = new OAuth2AuthorizationCodeRequestAuthenticationConverter();

        return (request) -> {
            OAuth2AuthorizationCodeRequestAuthenticationToken authorizationCodeRequestAuthentication =
                    (OAuth2AuthorizationCodeRequestAuthenticationToken) delegate.convert(request);
            return authorizationCodeRequestAuthentication;
        };
    }

    // ... validator and authorizationResponseHandler are same as reference
```

2. Authentication Provider

```java
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Component
@Slf4j
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    private final UserMapper userMapper;

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        String username = authentication.getName();
        String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();

        User user = getUser(username);
        validatePassword(username, user.getPassword(), password);

        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password, user.getAuthorities());
    }

    private User getUser(String username) {
        User user = userMapper.fetchUserByUsername(username);
        if (user == null)
            throw new BusinessException("oauth.user.0100", HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        return user;
    }

    private void validatePassword(String username, String userPassword, String reqPassword) {
        if(StringUtils.equals(userPassword, userMapper.fetchEncryptPassword(reqPassword)))
            return;

        userMapper.updateFailedLoginCount(username);
        throw new BusinessException("oauth.user.0100", HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return authentication.equals(
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
    }
}
```